# C Data Type Creation

Tags: c, class, struct, stdio, abstract-data-type

So I'm trying to learn C and I understand that it doesn't have classes. However, I have only been doing c++ programming and to create an object of a special type, let's say car, I would have to make a class for it. Something like this:

```
class Car {
     //code
};

void main() {
    Car c; //or Car c = new c(//constructor);
}
```

But I don't understand how C can't have classes when you something like [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/FILE/). You are declaring an variable of type `FILE`. So does that mean `FILE` is a struct in the `stdio.h` file? How do the data types work exactly in C?

Comment: Your point is very well taken - I agree with you

Comment: What part of Wikipedia's [`typedef`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) is obscure for you?

Comment: C has compound types ("structs"), but they can't have member functions, and so they're not "classes" in the OO sense. They're just compound types.

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't understand how C can't have classes

Because it's not strictly an object-oriented language.

> So does that mean FILE is a struct in the stdio.h file?

Yes.

> How do the data types work exactly in C?

There's an [entire paper](http://ldc.usb.ve/~vtheok/cursos/ci2125/material/curso%20C%202/815.pdf) on the topic (Google, first hit).

Sidenote: you **can** emulate object-oriented programming style in C using structs, it's just a matter of point of view whether or not you call something OO. For example, consider the usage of the infamous libcurl networking library:

```
CURL *hndl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(hndl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
curl_easy_perform(hndl);
curl_easy_cleanup(hndl);
```

This is essentially verbosely (explicitly) writing some OOP-code like this:

```
CURL hndl;
hndl->url = "http://example.com";
hndl->perform();
```

[There also is a paper](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) on this topic.

Comment: There's more than one paper in that subject, but alas not a single one was read before asking the question.

Comment: @Mithrandir Of course I didn't mean "there's only a single paper on this, that's why you didn't find it by the exhaustive googling you have done so far"... :P

Comment: The papers i have on C and programming types predate google and are actually written on paper. But of course, that's no longer relevant knowledge. ;-)

Comment: @Mithrandir Are you saying that K&R isn't anymore relevant? O.o

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `typedef` keyword to create types in C.  I usually do this sort of thing:

```
struct car_st {
    int numberOfSeats;
};
typedef struct car_st CAR;
typedef struct car_st * CAR_PTR;
```

Something like that.

Actually C can have classes, kind of.  Early implementations of C++ and Objective C were done with preprocessors, I think.  The problem is that you don't get true data hiding and methods.  You end up using function pointers for methods -- and that is both a maintenance nightmare and a lot of work to set up.  Not sure how you'd do inheritance, but it would probably be a mess of pointers to other structs.

So, yeah, you can slap something like that together.  But please don't.

Comment: About OO-C, take a look at [OO best practices for C programs](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/118253/1033) on programmers SE.

Answer (score 0):

The C equivalent would be to define a struct type for the `Car`'s attributes, and then define functions to manipulate objects of type `Car`.  That's essentially how the `FILE` type works:

```
FILE *f = fopen("afile.txt", "r"); // open a file for reading
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f);   // read from a file
fprintf(f, "%d on the wall", bottles--); // write formatted text to the file
```

At no point to we manipulate objects of `FILE` type directly; we just pass pass pointers back and forth.

There's no access control; you can't make some parts of a C struct `public` and others `private`; you can hide the implementation like so:

```
/** Car.h */
...
struct Car; 

struct Car *createCar(void);
void deleteCar(struct Car **theCar);
int startCar(struct Car *theCar);
...

/** Car.c */

#include "Car.h"
...
struct Car {
   char *make;
   char *model;
   int  year;
   ...
};

struct Car *createCar(void)
{
  struct Car *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
  if (p)
  {
    ... // initialize attributes
  }
  return p;
}

void deleteCar(struct Car **theCar)
{
  free(*theCar);
  *theCar = NULL;
}

void startCar(struct Car *theCar)
{
  theCar->running = 1; 
}

/** main.c */
#include "Car.h"
...
int main(void)
{
  struct Car *c = createCar();
  startCar(c);
  ...
  deleteCar(&c);
}
```

In this example, `main.c` only sees the forward declaration `struct Car;` in `Car.h`; since the type is incomplete, `main` can only declare *pointers* to type `struct Car`.  In `Car.c`, the struct type is completed with the definition `struct Car {char *make; char *model; ...};`, so functions within `Car.c` can access those members.